# EventSource and Internet Explorer

Tags: html, scala, playframework-2.0, server-sent-events

I have the following server side play code in order to provide an endpoint for HTML5 EventSources.

```
package controllers

import scala.util.matching
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
import play.api.libs.iteratee.{Concurrent, Enumeratee}
import play.api.libs.EventSource
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._

object Application extends Controller {

  /** Central hub for distributing chat messages */
  val (eventOut, eventChannel) = Concurrent.broadcast[JsValue]

  /** Enumeratee for filtering messages based on eventSpec */
  def filter(eventSpec: String) = Enumeratee.filter[JsValue] {
    json: JsValue => ("(?i)" + eventSpec).r.pattern.matcher((json \ "eventSpec").as[String]).matches
  }

  /** Enumeratee for detecting disconnect of SSE stream */
  def connDeathWatch(addr: String): Enumeratee[JsValue, JsValue] = 
    Enumeratee.onIterateeDone{ () => println(addr + " - SSE disconnected") }

  /** Controller action serving activity based on eventSpec */
  def events = Action { req =>
    println(req.remoteAddress + " - connected and subscribed for '" + eventSpec +"'")
    Ok.feed(eventOut
      &> filter(eventSpec) 
      &> Concurrent.buffer(50) 
      &> connDeathWatch(req.remoteAddress)
      &> EventSource()
    ).as("text/event-stream").withHeaders(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" -> "GET",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" -> "Content-Type"
    )
  }

}
```

My routes look like that

> GET     /events          controllers.Application.events

This server works perfectly fine when a Chrome browser is attaching itself via an EventSource object. Since the IE does not support EventSources, I am using the [this](https://github.com/remy/polyfills/blob/master/EventSource.js) polyfill library. Now the problem: The IE correctly subscribes to events, as I see the 'connected and subscribed' log output, but as soon as an event should be passed to this connection, it logs 'SSE disconnected'. What am I missing here? Some http headers?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be using CORS. (You're sending CORS headers.) If so, that may be the problem because the polyfill you are using doesn't support CORS. If you need CORS, you can use  [this polyfill instead](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/).